# How do I incorporate lazy loading with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, tinymce

I have the TinyMCE plugin on my site. When adding images in the textarea of the TinyMCE plugin, I want these images to have lazy loading incorporated. My site's thumbnails has a specific type of lazy loading where the src image is a gray background. Depending on the size of the user's screen, the type of image is loaded. Mobile images have the data attribute of data-mobile-src and the desktop images have the data attribute of data-large-src.

How do I make it so that once the textarea is uploaded my database's table, the images can be lazy loaded?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking in the future, you can use the `extended_valid_elements`.

This property is used to allow valid attributes, and you can specify a default value for them. So basically, this line adds `'loading=lazy'` automatically.

```js
extended_valid_elements : 'img[class|src|alt|title|width|loading=lazy]',
```

I understand some of you guys want to use `data-src` like techniques to support older browsers, I couldn't find a decent way to do using any of the configs TinyMCE provides. As solution, I think this works just fine

let `htmlString` be the content string received from tinymce and

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

doc.body.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
    img.setAttribute('data-src', img.src),
    img.removeAttribute('src')
})

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML) // your html to be sent to the server
```

You can even use this technique to change images into picture elements and srcset them. This technique can be implemented on the server side too, using the JSDom library.